# Wordpress: how to mass migrate posts from a category-ID to a taxonomy-TERM?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

(wordpress newby)

I've happily switched from a category based theme to a taxonomy based theme.
I've tons of categorized posts, and I'd like to make mass conversions to the new taxonomy scheme.

How can I massively migrate all posts belonging to a given CATEGORY (let's say category 123) to a given TAXONOMY TERM (let's say "ethnic-restaurant" in "eating" taxonomy)?

May be via MySQL command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table wp_term_relationships (object_id,term_taxonomy_id) links posts with categories, find the term_taxonomy_id of the old and the new category and write an update sql that moves posts from one to the other.